# How to create a config file bash script with variables inside

Tags: bash, variables, configuration-files

I'm learning BASH and trying to create a script that generates a configuration file in which I want to use variables. 
But of course, like this is a text file, the variable ${MONGO_PORT} is not being replaced by the value i need.

```
(
cat << MONGOD_CONF
# /etc/mongod.conf

systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: /datos/log/mongod.log
    logAppend: true

storage:
    dbPath: /datos/db
    engine: wiredTiger

net:
    port: ${MONGO_PORT}

security:
    authorization: enabled    
MONGOD_CONF
) > /etc/mongod.conf
```

- The first problem is about permission to create the file that I'm avoiding by creating the file in /tmp and moving it to /etc. Because this doesn't work.

  > ```
  >     sudo cat << MONGOD_CONF
  > ```
- The second and more important is about how to replace de variable by the value

Any way to make this work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `MONGO_PART` is set, the here-document is subject to parameter expansion and you'll get the parameter value in your file.

Use `tee` instead of `cat`, which can open the output file itself:

```
sudo tee /etc/mongod.conf > /dev/null << MONGOD_CONF
    ...
MONGOD_CONF
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a script with `sudo ...` the script will be executed with new environment. This is done for safety - to prevent injection of environment variables that may change the script behavior.

Two options to solve the problem: expand the config file as normal user, and perform the saving as `sudu`, or Use one of the options to allow environment variables to be passed to the `sudo` call

The first alternative is to change the script to expand the configuration file as the current user (with access to all parameters), and use the `sudo` only to place the file into /etc

```
(sudo cat > /etc/mongod.conf) <<MONGOD_CONF
...
MONGOD_CONF
```

The alternative option is to use `--preserve-env` option (possible to specify multiple variables as comma separated list).

```
sudo --preserve-env=MONGO_PORT
```

Strongly suggested to avoid the `-E` (--preserve-env, without parameters), as it may open the script to security exploitation.